# Как отменить действие при повторном нажатии кнопки?

Tags: javascript, button

1) Как отменить действие при повторном нажатии кнопки, как перенести данные в форму и как добавить кнопку очистки данных из формы ?
Лучший из вариантов как обновить данные при нажатии на кнопку повторно?

```js
function  generate() {
      const numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i);
      let resultSet = new Map();
      while (resultSet.size < 1000) {
        let nums = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5);
        let key = (nums.sort() + '');
        resultSet.set(key, nums);
      }
      resultSet.forEach(val => {
        const main = createTableWithContent(val.join('-'), "one");
        const additional = createTableWithContent(randInt(), "two");
        main.append(additional);
        document.body.append(main);
      })
    }
    
    function shuffle(arr) {
      return arr.map(el => {
        return {
          item: el,
          sort: Math.random()
        }
      }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
    }
    
    function randInt(min = 1, max = 4) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    
    function createTableWithContent(content, className) {
      const tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
      tableEl.className = className || "";
      tableEl.append(content);
      return tableEl;
      
    }
```

```html
 <input type="button" value="Генератор чисел" onclick="generate()" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так, может пригодится

Создал блок

```
<div id="myTable"></div>
```

В него идут ваши значения

После нажатия на кнопку, данные очищаются

```
document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = "";
```

```js
function  generate() {
 document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = "";
      const numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i);
      let resultSet = new Map();
      while (resultSet.size < 1000) {
        let nums = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5);
        let key = (nums.sort() + '');
        resultSet.set(key, nums);
      }
      resultSet.forEach(val => {
        const main = createTableWithContent(val.join('-'), "one");
        const additional = createTableWithContent(randInt(), "two");
        main.append(additional);
        document.getElementById("myTable").append(main);
      })
    }
    
    function shuffle(arr) {
      return arr.map(el => {
        return {
          item: el,
          sort: Math.random()
        }
      }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
    }
    
    function randInt(min = 1, max = 4) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    
    function createTableWithContent(content, className) {
      const tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
      tableEl.className = className || "";
      tableEl.append(content);
      return tableEl;
      
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Генератор чисел" onclick="generate()" />
<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как отменить действие при повторном нажатии кнопки

```js
function generate() {
  // !!!
  var old = document.body.querySelectorAll(".one");
  if (old.length > 0) {
    for (var iOld = old.length - 1; iOld >= 0; iOld--) {
      old[iOld].parentNode.removeChild(old[iOld]);
    }
    return;
  }
  // !!!

  const numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i);
  let resultSet = new Map();
  while (resultSet.size < 1000) {
    let nums = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5);
    let key = (nums.sort() + '');
    resultSet.set(key, nums);
  }
  resultSet.forEach(val => {
    const main = createTableWithContent(val.join('-'), "one");
    const additional = createTableWithContent(randInt(), "two");
    main.append(additional);
    document.body.append(main);
  })
}

function shuffle(arr) {
  return arr.map(el => {
    return {
      item: el,
      sort: Math.random()
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
}

function randInt(min = 1, max = 4) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function createTableWithContent(content, className) {
  const tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
  tableEl.classList.add(className || ""); // !!!
  tableEl.append(content);
  return tableEl;

}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Генератор чисел" onclick="generate()" />
```

Это не понял:

> , как перенести данные в форму и как добавить кнопку очистки данных из
>   формы ?